# Extension for category NSMutableArray Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I am a beginner programmer and I was given the assignment to write an extension to the category `NSMutableArray`. In googled it, i found very little information and did not understand how to do it.
I need to write an extension to Shell sort. I could use `NSSortDescriptor`, but expansion should be given the sort algorithm, a standard `NSSortDescriptor` method is not applicable for this. If there is some sort of a normal user Associative References and how to use it, it is really helped. Because, what I found - is not for me.

Comment: Can you share what code you have so far? The way your question is worded is very broad.

Comment: What is your exact issue? Is it the extension part (creating a category on NSMutableArray), or the Shell Sort part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here it is...

**NSMutableArray+Sort.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSMutableArray (Sort)

    -(void)sortArrayUsingShellSort;

@end
```

**NSMutableArray+Sort.m**

```
#import "NSMutableArray+Sort.h"
@implementation NSMutableArray (Sort)

    -(void)sortArrayUsingShellSort
    {
         // tasks
         // #1. access the unsorted array using self
         // #2. sort the array using your shell sort, no one gonna do that for you, you have to do that yourself. Re-arrange the items or the array.

    }

@end
```

some useful link for shell sort

1. [Tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/shell_sort_algorithm.htm)
2. [interactivepuython](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheShellSort.html)
3. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort)
4. [Toptal](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms/shell-sort)

Into your 
**main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> // not necessary actually, as it is already imported into our NSMutableArray+Sort.h
#import "NSMutableArray+Sort.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:15]
                                            ]];


    NSLog(@"array before sorting %@", myArray);

    //here goes your sorting category function call
    [myArray sortArrayUsingShellSort];

    NSLog(@"array after sorting %@", myArray);
}
```

Comment: `UITabBarItem`? And make it appropriate for `NSMutableArray` as per question maybe?

Comment: Ooooh. How to use this extension in main?

Comment: It was a typo @CRD, you just have to import the "NSMutableArray+Sort.h", then call it's functionality, nothing else @ owner

Comment: @LK. Mishenko: Extensions add funtionality to an existing class. NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray new]; [myArray sortArrayUsingShellSort].

Comment: @Ratul Sharker: maybe add usage example to your answer for our fellow student.